# InetAddress.isReachable(timeout) cannot reach Host in other Domain

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, dns, ping

I'm working on a project on creating a pinger that will ping massively around 400 ips given a .csv file.  The .csv file is passed to a JTable and for each row of this table I create and run threads that will ping IPs to another domain that the java program is running.

Problem is that none of those IPs cannot be reached through the isReachable() method of the java.net.InetAddress class.  I can ping through the ping command from cmd.exe of windows from the same pc that the java program is running the same IPs that the .csv file refers to successfully.

I have used 3 different methods to test my program (the original isReachable(), one method that uses sockets that tries to open a socket on port 7, and last method that uses the Windows ping command) and only the one that uses the ping command of windows manages to reach all of the IPs.

That said the program works but it uses too much resources given that for each thread now I do open a process for the Win ping command to work.  Plus as I am measuring the response time for the ping it comes out to be away from the real ping command.

Note that using the isReachable() method of Java and editing the .csv file on the IP section giving an external IP for www.google.com or so it does respond nicely.  Only those IPs on another domain do not respond. I have asked the administrators to open the path from Firewall on ICMP, TCP/UDP ports 7,22 to test again my program (not yet implemented) to see if I have more luck with it.

**My question** is what is wrong with using the InetAddress.isReachable() on Domain (172.) to Domain (10.) base and if there is more to ask from the admin team so the method can do what is designed to.

I'm pasting the code of my thread bellow:

```
package my.pinger3;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PingerThread3 implements Runnable {

//Declaring global variables
JTable jt;
int timeout = 400;  //Initialise values to something resonable
int sleepTime = 10000;  //Initialise values to something resonable
long startTime;
long endTime;
boolean boolVal = false;
int countAll;
int countFailed;
int row = 0;
final int COL_IP = 2;
final int COL_DEL = 3;
final int COL_SEN = 4;
final int COL_OK = 5;
final int COL_REA = 6;
//Define the openPort var that tells the isReachable() method what port   to use for socket connection
final int openPort = 7;   //Use the 7port as some say that is the open port for ICMP 

//Constructor
PingerThread3(JTable jt, int row, int timeout, int sleepTime) {
    super();
    this.jt = jt;
    this.row = row;
    this.timeout = timeout;
    this.sleepTime = sleepTime;

    //Initialise global variables
    startTime = 0;
    endTime = 0;
    countAll = 0;
    countFailed = 0;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        //InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName((String) jt.getValueAt(row, COL_IP));
        //System.out.println((String)jt.getValueAt(row, COL));
        while (true) {
            //Catch the time before reachable() method is called
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //Check if the address is reachable
            /*
            Use the InetAddress isReachable(timeout) method through isReachable(address)
            */
            //boolVal = isReachable(address);
            /*
            Use the socket isReachsble Version method
            */
            //boolVal = isReachable(jt.getValueAt(row, COL_IP).toString(), openPort, timeout);
            /*
            Use the hardcoded Widnows ping command method
            */
            boolVal = isReachable(jt.getValueAt(row, COL_IP).toString());
            //Catch the time after reachable() method has been called
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            //Display the Delay column data in the specific cell
            jt.setValueAt((Long) (endTime - startTime), row, COL_DEL);

            /*
            Display the number of times the reachable() was called which actually is
            not equal to the number of requests done on the IP (ICMP port 7) given.
             */
            jt.setValueAt((Integer) countAll, row, COL_SEN);

            if (boolVal) {
                jt.setValueAt("reached", row, COL_REA);
            } else {
                jt.setValueAt("NOT reached", row, COL_REA);

                //Increase the counter for failed operations
                countFailed++;
                //Set the color of this cell to red

            }

            //Display the %OK of packets send/received
            jt.setValueAt(calcOK(countAll, countFailed), row, COL_OK);

            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PingerThread3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

/*
The InetAddress isReachable() method
*/
private boolean isReachable(InetAddress ia) {
    Boolean boolLocalVal = false;
    try {
        boolLocalVal = ia.isReachable(timeout);
        //increase the counter for all calls of this method
        countAll++;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return boolLocalVal;
}

/*
The Socket version of isReachable
 */
private boolean isReachable(String addr, int openPort, int timeOutMillis) throws IOException {
    // Any Open port on other machine
    // openPort =  22 - ssh, 80 or 443 - webserver, 25 - mailserver etc.
    Socket soc = new Socket();
    try {
        countAll++;
        soc.connect(new InetSocketAddress(addr, openPort), timeOutMillis);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }finally {
        soc.close();
    }
}

/*
The hard coded Windows ping version of isReachable() note that this is the worst 
solution in resources and accuracy based observations
*/
private boolean isReachable(String add) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    countAll++;
    // in case of Linux change the 'n' to 'c'
    Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -n 1 "+add);
    int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
    boolean reachable = (returnVal == 0);
    p1.destroy();
    return reachable;
}

private Double calcOK(int cntAll, int cntFailed) {
    Double value = ((Double.valueOf(cntAll) - Double.valueOf(cntFailed)) / Double.valueOf(cntAll)) * 100;
    return Math.round(value * 100.0) / 100.0;
}
}
```

Comment: You are inconsistently incrementing your count before and after success in the different methods.

Comment: What *problem* are you trying to solve by pinging all those servers?  Pinging a server is a horribly unreliable way to tell if a server is functional.  It may be working fine, and anything along the path may block pings.  Even if you get a reply, that doesn't mean whatever service(s) you care about are both reachable and working.  A ping failure doesn't tell you the server isn't there, and a positive ping doesn't tell you the service(s) you want are both accessible and working.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I just need to verify that the hosts are alive as a machine overall not a specific service.  I need to understand how InetAddress.isReachable() is working in order to try to "clear" the path to those hosts.  There are some articles that I found through stackoverflow but are not so clear on how isReachable() is working.